# Dependency versioning resolving using Gradle

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I am developing an Android library as .aar and I encountered this issue:

An host app using direct dependency A version 1
and is dependent on my library which is using dependency A version 2.

Gradle will resolve to the higher version on default when building the host app.
This resolving will result in failed build of the host app build in case dependency A version 2 is no backward compatible.

Is there a way for bundling the dependency A version 1 of the Android Library in the aar so it will be available with version 2 will in runtime?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want a project's transitive dependencies to be brought into your project, you need to set the `transitive` flag to false.

Your dependency tree currently looks something like this:

```
app
 \- libA:1.0
 \- yourLibrary
     \- libA:2.0
```

Since your app relies on version 1.0 of the library, you don't want version 2.0 in your app. Version 2.0 is a transitive dependency of your library, so in this case the following Gradle dependency will prevent Gradle from pulling in `libA:2.0` from your library:

```
compile('com.example:yourLibrary:1.0.0') {
    transitive = false
}
```

Comment: The goal is to make it is straightforward for the app developer to add our aar / library(one line of groovy code if possible). your solution force the host app developer to manually add libA in case he doesn't use libA at all. is there a more elegant way? tx